# Enzyme : How to test the local state is updated or not?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a function which is called when item is selected in dropdown. The function updates the state : `value` when list ListOfTemplates changes.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import * as getData from '../../services/DataService';

class Container extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props) 
        this.props.actions.getTemplates(1);
        this.state = {
            value: 1
        }

    }

    handlelistOfTemplates = (value, index) => {
        this.setState({ value });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    render() {
        return(

                <ListOfTemplates listOfTemplates={this.props.listOfTemplates} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handlelistOfTemplates}/>
            );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps({state}) {
    return {
        listOfTemplates: state.listOfTemplates
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(getData, dispatch)
    };
   }
module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Container);
```

How do i unit test `handlelistOfTemplates` function?

Here is my test :

```
import React from 'react';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import expect from 'expect';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import { createMockStore, createMockDispatch } from 'redux-test-utils';

import Container from './Container';
const shallowWithStore = (component, store) => {
    const context = {
        store,
        muiTheme: getMuiTheme(),
    };

    const childContextTypes = {
        muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }
    return shallow(component, { context, childContextTypes });
};
let store;
const loadComponent = (testState) => {

    const props = {
        actions: {
            getTemplates: () => {return Promise.resolve()}
        }
    }
    store = createMockStore(testState)
    return shallowWithStore(<Container {...props}/>, store);
}

const getFakeState = () => {
    return {
        listOfTemplates: [],

    };
}


export default shallowWithStore;

describe('Container', () => {
    let testState, component;


    describe("when Appeal template is selected from select template dropdown", () => {
        beforeAll(() => {
            testState = getFakeState();
            component = loadComponent(testState);

        });

        fit('should update the content in editor', (done) => {
            component.dive().find('ListOfTemplates').props().onChange(2);
            component.update();

            expect(component.dive().state().value).toEqual(2); // it return 1 instead of 2
            done();

        });
    });
});
```

Is there a way to test the local state getting updated? Where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I tried with  `component.dive().setProps({});` and      `component.dive().instance().forceUpdate();` but still the state is not updated in test.